# unsigned three = 1 in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

See [this link](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d158fc7f36a25e19791d25a55da5623399a2644f/fs/ext4/resize.c#L698) (relevant function pasted below for the lazy).

```
/*
 * Check that all of the backup GDT blocks are held in the primary GDT block.
 * It is assumed that they are stored in group order.  Returns the number of
 * groups in current filesystem that have BACKUPS, or -ve error code.
 */
static int verify_reserved_gdb(struct super_block *sb,
                   ext4_group_t end,
                   struct buffer_head *primary)
{
    const ext4_fsblk_t blk = primary->b_blocknr;
    unsigned three = 1;
    unsigned five = 5;
    unsigned seven = 7;
    unsigned grp;
    __le32 *p = (__le32 *)primary->b_data;
    int gdbackups = 0;

    while ((grp = ext4_list_backups(sb, &three, &five, &seven)) < end) {
        if (le32_to_cpu(*p++) !=
            grp * EXT4_BLOCKS_PER_GROUP(sb) + blk){
            ext4_warning(sb, "reserved GDT %llu"
                     " missing grp %d (%llu)",
                     blk, grp,
                     grp *
                     (ext4_fsblk_t)EXT4_BLOCKS_PER_GROUP(sb) +
                     blk);
            return -EINVAL;
        }
        if (++gdbackups > EXT4_ADDR_PER_BLOCK(sb))
            return -EFBIG;
    }

    return gdbackups;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why this variable is initialised like this, and what this function is doing?

Comment: Looking up ext4_list_backups gives some insight - http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/fs/ext4/resize.c#L644

Comment: The variables `three`, `five` and `seven` hold *powers* of three, five and seven.  1 is 3 to the power of 0.

Answer (score 7):

See line 00296 [here](http://kerneldox.com/kdox-ubuntu-natty/d8/dac/ext4_2resize_8c_source.html). Comment says:

```
00295 /*
00296  * Iterate through the groups which hold BACKUP superblock/GDT copies in an
00297  * ext4 filesystem.  The counters should be initialized to 1, 5, and 7 before
00298  * calling this for the first time.  In a sparse filesystem it will be the
00299  * sequence of powers of 3, 5, and 7: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 25, 27, 49, 81, ...
00300  * For a non-sparse filesystem it will be every group: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
00301  */
```

In short it seems to me `three` should be initialized to `1` to enable the function `ext4_list_backups` return `1`.